# Why bss value shown by size command doesn't increase even after adding uninitialized global variable?

Tags: c, ubuntu, size, memory-layout

I am using ubuntu 64 bit and I am trying to find the size of `.bss` segment for various variables as below.

**first program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
}
```

`size` command is giving below result for the executable generated by above program.

```
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1115        552       8    1675     68b a.out
```

**second program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 10;
main()
{
}
```

size command is giving below result for the executable generated by above program.

```
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1115        556       4    1675     68b a.out
```

third program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
main()
{
}
```

`size` command is giving below result for the executable generated by above program.

```
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1115        552       8    1675     68b a.out
```

Note:

I haven't used any flags while compiling.

Could some one please clairfy below questions?

```
1) Why `bss` is 8 bytes for first program even though there are no uninitialized global or static variables?
2) Why `bss` is reduced to 4 bytes when I added initialized global variable in second program?
3) Why `bss` is showing 8 bytes for the third program?
4) What are dec and hex in the output given by size command?
```

Comment: Your program is not doing anything, so this variable is probably optimized away.

Comment: You pose the question as if the sizes of the various segments are fully determined by the source code alone.  In fact, the compiler and (especially) linker have a great deal of latitude in this area.

Comment: What compiler flags did you use? And what does `objdump -x a.out` say?

Comment: `main()` - that's not valid C since 18 years. Get a more recent book. And ask your teacher for help with your homework.

Comment: @Olaf : This is not homework. I am trying to see the sizes for different variables. I hope just main() is fine for testing.

Comment: Your question doesn't have a definite answer, it's just the way the compiler works. Different compilers could give you different results. On your first example, the compiler decided to give BSS 8 bytes because reasons. On the second, it allocates the variable on the data segment and gives BSS 4 bytes. Maybe it has a thing for the BSS segment? You know what I would do...put those programs on a debugger and break on the BSS segment.

Comment: @kadina: Undefined behaviour. Use a modern compiler with standard C (for gcc: `-std=c11` or `gnu11`), this should not compile cleanly Also follow [ask], you missed relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is your coworker. You left before I could tell you your answers.

> 1) Why bss is 8 bytes for first program even though there are no
>   uninitialized global or static variables?

I don't have a clear answer for this. I suspect the compiler is using 4 bytes for something and because the data segment is already 69*8 = 552, it has to allocate a full 8 bytes for the bss.

> 2) Why bss is reduced to 4 bytes when I added initialized global
>   variable in second program?

data + bss will always be divisible by 8. Because your program only needs 4 bytes for the variable, the compiler takes the unused bytes from bss into the data segment.

> 3) Why bss is showing 8 bytes for the third program?

This goes back to 1 and 2, when you aren't initializing your variable it is getting put in bss. bss at this point has 2 ("a" + an internal compiler variable) variables in it. You can test this by adding additional uninitialized variables. Every other variable you add (starting with the first, if bss was 4) will increase bss by 8.

> 4) What are dec and hex in the output given by size command?

data + text + bss = dec, same value in hex

Hope this helps. 
Swing by my desk if you'd like to know more.

Comment: Thanks SnickySnacks. I will stop by your desk tomorrow.

Comment: Where do you know that?  And why data + bss will always be divisible by 8.

Comment: Mostly just experimenting. Every other 4-byte variable you add in his example would increase bss by 8, which suggests that it allocates 8 bytes at a time.

0 variables: 544/8
1 initialized variable: 548/4
2 initialized variables: 552/8
2 initialized, 1 uninitialized variables: 552/8
2 initialized, 2 uninitialized variables: 552/16
2 initialized, 3 uninitialized variables: 552/16
2 initialized, 4 uninitialized variables: 552/24

etc.